# Protactor: should I put assertions in my PageObject?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, pageobjects, e2e-testing

I have multiple scenarios in which I'd like to test pretty much the same things.

I am testing a backoffice and I have widgets (like autocomplete search for instance). And I want to make sure that the widget is not broken given that:

1. I just browse an article page
2. I saved a part of the article, which reloaded the page
3. 1+2 then I played with some other widgets which have possible side effects
4. ...

My first tought was to add some reusable methods to my WidgetPO (testWidgetStillWorksX ~)

After browsing on the subjet: there's some pros & cons on the subject as said in http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html

So how do you handle / where do you put your reusable tests and what are the difficulties/advantages you've had with either methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too much broad to answer. Best way to write tests using PageObject model is to exclude assertions from the PageObject file. To cut short here's a small explanation -

Difficulties -

- Assertions are always a part of the test case/script. So its better to put them in the scripts that you write.
- Assertions in PageObject disturbs the modularity and reusability of the code.
- Difficulty in writing/extending general functions in pageobject.
- Third person would need to go to your pageobject from test script each and everytime to check your assertions.

Advantages -

- You can always add methods/functions that do repetitive tasks in your pageObject which performs some operation(like waiting for element to load, getting text of an element, etc...) other than assertions and returns a value.
- Call the functions of PageObject from your tests and use the returned value from them to perform assertions in your tests.
- Assertions in test scripts are easy to read and understand without a need to worry about the implementation of pageobjects.

[Here's a good article of pageobjects](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I know there no definite answer on the subject. Just trying to get differents views on the matter.  --  In the end, where would you put you're repetitive tests (like testing a widget works under different scenario ?) I am leaning toward a reusable spec file (specs wrapped in functions and exported as a module)

Comment: Your repetitive tests would go under pageobject files but they shouldn't contain assertions as it would cause problems to others who would try to use those functions. They should be written in a generalized way.